# Undertow Invalid Logger Interface

Tags: java, logging, minecraft, undertow

I'm trying to start a simple api server with the [undertow.io](http://undertow.io/) API. Here is my startup code.

```
this.server = Undertow.builder().addHttpListener(this.port, this.host).setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
            exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");
        }
    }).build();
   this.server.start();
```

I'll get this Error:

```
    [22:26:46] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling MWS v1.0-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:113) ~[?:?]
    at me.ripes.mws.server.ApiServer.startServer(ApiServer.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at me.ripes.mws.MWS.onEnable(MWS.java:20) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:271) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:337) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:376) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:326) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:750) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:540) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:650) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:636) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.aM(DedicatedServer.java:437) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:400) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:678) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:576) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-d276ab1-1f6c04c]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid logger interface io.undertow.UndertowLogger (implementation not found in org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader@12cb152a)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2556) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529) ~[?:?]
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516) ~[?:?]
    at io.undertow.UndertowLogger.<clinit>(UndertowLogger.java:59) ~[?:?]
    ... 19 more
```

I think it's a problem with the undertow logger but i have no idea to fix it.
Please help me :)

Comment: I am finding [this message](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/undertow-dev/2013-February/000155.html) with the same problem and the [reply](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/undertow-dev/2013-February/000157.html) indicates that a recompile fixed it. [This post](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/222022?_sscc=t) comments that some "crappy intra-workspace dependencies" broke it and was fixed by disabling the maven dependencies. Either of those help?

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace contains a lot these things: ~[?:?]. If you are running proguard on your jar to minify and obfuscate than it might be deleting the logger interface you need. Disable proguard and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct dependencies? I used the same dependencies as mentioned in the official site and it worked for me under Java 1.8.

**HelloWorldServer.java**

```
package undertow;

import io.undertow.Undertow;
import io.undertow.server.HttpHandler;
import io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange;
import io.undertow.util.Headers;

public class HelloWorldServer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {      
        HelloWorldServer helloWorldServer = new HelloWorldServer();
        helloWorldServer.initiateServer();
    }

    private void initiateServer() {

        this.server = Undertow.builder().addHttpListener(this.port, this.host).setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World 312");
            }
        }).build();
       this.server.start();
    }

    Undertow server = null;
    int port= 8080;
    String host = "localhost";
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
        <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
        <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
        <artifactId>undertow-websockets-jsr</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Console-out**

```
Jul 11, 2017 10:45:33 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.3.6.Final
Jul 11, 2017 10:45:33 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.6.Final
```

localhost:8080 prints "Hello World 312"

Comment: Thank you! But I it's not a standalone application. It's only a plugin for Spigot (Spigotmc.org)

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid logger interface io.undertow.UndertowLogger (implementation not found in org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader@12cb152a)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2556) ~[?:?]
```

`io.undertow.UndertowLogger` is an interface, which is annotated using one of the `jboss.logging` annotation. When the interface is compiled, there is annotation processor executed, which will generate the logger implementation.

The error message means, that at runtime, JBoss logger was unable to load the implementation class.

If the class in question is built by you, check the annotation processor was being run during the build. Maven sometimes goes crazy and refuses to run annotation processor. If so, `mvn clean` usually resolves that.

If that class is provided by a third party, you are maybe missing some dependencies.